# Amount changes if dropdown is changed PHP+JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In the table below, I have 2 items named "Jacket" and "Uniform". Each item has a  dropdown to select the desired quantity. What I want to happen is for the amount to automatically change when the quantity is changed. For example, the unit price of a uniform is 1,400 Pesos. If the user desires to buy 2 uniforms, the amount will automatically change from 1,400 to 2,800 Pesos. For "Jacket" the amount automatically changes when the quantity changes. The unit price of a jacket is 700 Pesos. Hence, when the quantity is changed from 1 to 2, the amount changed from 700 to 1,400 Pesos. I don't understand why the same is not happening to "Uniform", that is, when the quantity changes the amount does not change. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see my code below. Thank you very much.

[image]
Here are my code: 
PHP

```
 @foreach($data['tuition_other'] as $other)
     <tr>
         <td>{{Hashids::encode($other->id)}}</td>
         <td>{{$other->item_name}}</td>
         <td id="item_amt">{{number_format($other->item_amount,2,'.',',')}}</td>
         <td>
             <select name="item_quantity" class="iqty_class" id="iqty_id">
                 @for ($i=1; $i<=$other->max_quantity; $i++)                                                                            
                     <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                 @endfor
             </select>
             <input type="hidden" id="item_val" value="{{ $other->item_amount }}">
         </td>
         <? $total_other += $other->item_amount; ?>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

JS

```
$('body').on('change','.iqty_class', function(){
    var item_amt = $('#item_val').val();
    var item_qty = $('.iqty_class').val();
    var total_amt =  item_amt * item_qty;
    var c = total_amt.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
    $("#item_amt").html(c);
});
```

Comment: because of that: `<td id="item_amt">`. An id needs to be unique, but you have the same id for that field in every row. So js doesn't know which one to update. Same goes for `id="item_val"`

Comment: you need to find another way to name and find these fields/inputs. Either give them unique id's or select the right one in 'onChange'-function via smth like `parent().children('.item_val')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this way:

Blade

```
@foreach($data['tuition_other'] as $other)
     <tr>
         <td>{{Hashids::encode($other->id)}}</td>
         <td>{{$other->item_name}}</td>
         <td class="item_amt">{{number_format($other->item_amount,2,'.',',')}}</td>
         <td>
             <select name="item_quantity" class="iqty_class" id="iqty_id">
                 @for ($i=1; $i<=$other->max_quantity; $i++)                                                                            
                     <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                 @endfor
             </select>
             <input type="hidden" class="item_val" value="{{ $other->item_amount }}">
         </td>
         <? $total_other += $other->item_amount; ?>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('change','.iqty_class', function(){
    var item_amt = $(this).parent().children('.item_val').val();
    var item_qty = $(this).val();
    var total_amt =  item_amt * item_qty;
    var c = total_amt.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
    $(this).parent().parent().children('.item_amt').html(c);
});
```